# cakephp retrieving multiple values in a column

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I want to retrieve multiples values from a field. the code I am using this this

```
$conditions = array('Tag.name'=>$compare);//$compare = array('value1', 'value2',..);
$values = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

But It keeps coming out like this

```
    SELECT `Tag`.`id`, `Tag`.`name`, `Tag`.`count` FROM `tags` AS `Tag` WHERE `Tag`.`name` IN ('tag2', ' tag1', ' one tag')
```

Problem is it only retrieves the first value given. instead of all the values . How do I get it to select all the values in the array.

Comment: Is that the entire query that it is generating?

Comment: Are you sure there are 'tag2', ' tag1', ' one tag' tags in your tags table? Paste the var_dump($values); print out back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Cake are you using?

But the main thing is that your conditions needs to be in a fields array.

```
find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('name' => 'Thomas Anderson'),
'fields' => array('name', 'email'),
'order' => 'field3 DESC',
'recursive' => 2,
'group' => 'type'
));
```

Ref, [Model::find() API Docs](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelfind)

The reason your query is not working is that you need to move it into that pattern..

So your query would be,

```
$compare = array('value1', 'value2');
$values = $this->Model->find('all', array('fields' => $compare));
```

Not sure on your example if you meant to omit it, but always best to include the model you are running the find against :)